# Base on\upon something

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> "Their relationship was based on mutual respect"

Why do we always use "base on" in passive? Can we use it *not* in the passive?

Comment: It is best to only ask one question per post. I have edited your question to only include the first one. If you still want to ask the second one, please ask it as a separate question :).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use "base on" in the active voice. It means

> 1. To ground (an opinion, a conclusion, etc.) on — i.e. to give reasons for something
> 2. To derive (a work) from — i.e. to adapt something
>      
>    ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/base_on))

Note that in the active voice, the object comes between "base" and "on".
Here are two examples:

> They decided to **base** their relationship **on** mutual respect.
>
> John Milton **based** his masterpiece "Paradise Lost" **on** ancient epic poems.

One particular construction in which you *must* use the passive voice is this:

> **Based on** our previous results, we decided that a follow-up study was necessary.

Here, "based on" is a fixed expression that means something like "in light of" or "given".

Answer (score 0):

The preposition *on* in your example has nothing to do with the type of voice a verb is in. Rather, the preposition to be used *after* a verb has to do with the prepositional valency required by that verb.

For the verb `to base [something] on [something]`, the preposition to be used after it, which which it forms a unit of sense often distinct from that of the verb when taken on its own, is always *on*.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't right that "base " is always used in the passive voice. You can write your sentence in a different way :

1) They based their relationship  on mutual respect. (It's an active use)

I am giving you some more examples to completely understand.

2) ‘I've read poor reviews here, and elsewhere, about the
conductor, so I base my conclusions on that…!’

3) ‘Dershwitz based his conclusion on witnesses who said
Reid had slurred speech and difficulty holding up his
head at the start of the interview.’

4) ‘Although he based his films on Kannada novels, the
novelists complained that their stories had been
altered.’

Hope it helps you out.